# Aplicando automapper a un método Single - predicate

Tags: c#, automapper

Tengo un método *Single*, el cual tiene un `predicate` que me tiene que devolver `Dto`, muestro el código.

Persistencia:

```
public static Proveedor Single(Expression<Func<Proveedor, bool>> predicate)
{
    using (var context = new DemoContext())
    {
        return context.Proveedores.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    }
}
```

Lógica:

```
public static ProveedorDto Single(Expression<Func<ProveedorDto, bool>> predicate)
{
    //Tiene que devolver Dto
}
```

No sé si podría ser así.

```
public static ProveedorDto Single(Expression<Func<ProveedorDto, bool>> predicate)
{
    config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<ProveedorDto, Proveedor>());
    var proveedor = config.CreateMapper().Map<Proveedor>(predicate);
    return ProveedorRepository.Single(proveedor);
}
```

Pero me da el siguiente error:

> (variable local) `Proveedor proveedor`
>
> Argumento 1: No se puede convertir de `Demo.EntidadesDominio.Proveedor` a
> `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Demo.EntidadesDominio.Proveedor,bool>>`

El método de persistencia me devuelve `Proveedor` pero en presentación tengo que devolver `Dto`.

Entonces en la `Lógica` tengo que hacer aplicar `automapper`. Ese metodo me tiene que devolver `Dto` para mostrarlo a `Presentación`.

Se me complica aplicar `automapper` por el `predicate`.

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Nota: Estoy usando la última versión de `automapper`.

Answer (score 0):

Estas confundiendo la obtención de datos con el mapeo. El predicado solo seria para filtrar los datos del contexto y el mapeo se aplica una vez obtenido los datos del contexto.

```
public static ProveedorDto Single(Expression<Func<ProveedorDto, bool>> predicate)
{
    // La definición es: CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>()
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Proveedor, ProveedorDto>());
    //or
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Proveedor, ProveedorDto>());


    // La obtención de los datos filtrados con el predicado
    var proveedor = ProveedorRepository.Single(predicate);


    // El mapeo de los datos obtenidos al Dto para la presentación
    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    // or
    var mapper = new Mapper(config);
    ProveedorDto dto = mapper.Map<ProveedorDto>(proveedor);
    // or
    ProveedorDto dto = Mapper.Map<ProveedorDto>(proveedor);

    return dto;
}
```

[Ver AutoMapper Getting-started](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started)

Comment: Como puedes ver en mi código en persistencia(acceso a datos espera Proveedor y el método de lógica ha devolver ProveedorDto. Pero en lógica cuando llamo al método de persistencia tengo que enviarle Proveedor pero como le envio el predicate de lógica le estoy enviando dto por eso me sale error que no se puede convertir Proveedor a ProveedorDto